# Где можно найти каталог автомобилей с удобной выдачей, например JSON?

Tags: json, api

Всем привет. Для нашего проекта нужен справочный каталог существующих в мире автомобилей. Самое важное, это код или название двигателя чтобы было обязательно. Может кто знает такие сервисы? Можно платные, можно бесплатные. Сейчас парсим drom.ru/catalog но хочется информацию в более простом и адекватном виде.